# Weird CSS/browser local storage bug

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox

EDIT: JUST DISCOVERED THIS IS HAPPENING ON FIREFOX BUT NOT CHROME

ANOTHER EDIT: This only happens locally, strangely enough.  On github it works fine, I clone it I get this bug.  Make of that what you will.  I guess that means its not a big deal.

Alright, on my portfolio webpage, I give the user an option to choose three different "skins" from a drop down menu in the navbar (None (default), Christmas, and Easter).  This simply uses a script javascript to change the attribute in the style sheet tag.  Here's how it looks:

```
function skinCheck() {
    var skin = localStorage.getItem("skin");
    if (skin == null) {
        skin = "default";
    }
    $("link[type='text/css']").attr('href', "style/" + skin + '.css');
    $('select option[value="' + skin + '"]').attr("selected", true);
}


function setSkin() {
    console.log(event.target.value);

    localStorage.setItem("skin", event.target.value);

    skinCheck();
}
```

Now when a user switches skins, the local storage remembers this, so if you are "Easter" in one section, you are "Easter" in the next, and you will be "Easter" when you close out and come back.

Each stylesheet just changes some colors.  The vast majority of the information between them is identical. This can make updating my style very tedious, because I have to update all three style sheets most of the time.

So, I had an idea.  What if I put two stylesheets in my head tag?  One on top with, and one below.  The one below is what the script changes.  So now my script looks like this:

```
function skinCheck() {
    var skin = localStorage.getItem("skin");
    if (skin == null) {
        skin = "default";
    }
    $(".subStyle").attr('href', "style/" + skin + '.css');
    $('select option[value="' + skin + '"]').attr("selected", true);
}


function setSkin() {
    console.log(event.target.value);

    localStorage.setItem("skin", event.target.value);

    skinCheck();
}
```

This works well enough, except now, the skin choice doesn't seem to persist from page to page like it used to.  Each section of my portfolio is remembered on its own.  IE the "About Me" becomes Christmas and stays Christmas, but the Contact page will not change until I change it, or visa-versa.

What on Earth could be causing this?

EDIT:

Here's an HTML snippet from the top of one of my pages, to give you a better idea how this works:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en-us">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Downloads</title>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

   <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" class = "subStyle" type="text/css" href="style/default.css">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <script src="portfolio.js"></script>



 </head>

 <body onload="showStuff(), skinCheck()">
```

Here is where the skin is selected:

```
 <span class = "skin" style = "float:right;">Change Skin? <select onChange = "setSkin(event);">
        <option value = "default">None</option>
        <option value = "easter">Easter</option>
        <option value = "christmas">Christmas</option></select> 
    </span>
```

Comment: The first step would be to `console.log` the value from `localStorage`. Do you see the correct value on every page load for every page?

Comment: It reflects what's displayed on the page if you that's what you mean.  Its correct in that sense.

Comment: Did you call `skinCheck` initially when the page loads? @DennisM

Comment: Yes.  Infact, let me edit my comment to include some HTML snippets.

Comment: @DennisM, this is not exactly what I mean. As per my understanding, your expectation is that the skin that is set on one page will be set for all pages. It means that once the skin is set, it is stored in the `localcStorage` and then read on each page load of any other pages. This implies that if you set some skin on some page, you should see `console.log` logging the same skin for all pages.

Comment: Yeah, and I don't.

Comment: Your `onload` syntax is not correct. It should be `<body onload="showStuff(); skinCheck()">` (with semicolon instead of comma) @DennisM

Comment: You're referencing an `event` in your setSkin function, but there is no event argument for that function. So whatever event is happening that allows a `localStorage` set call to work would be grabbed from the outer scope, and that event may not be getting triggered when you think it should. You haven't shared any code that calls setSkin, so it's hard to tell what the event might actually be.

Comment: Adding an event parameter in the JS file doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a quick (and ugly) replication on CodePen to try and diagnose the issue. While the rest of your code is not published above the only way I could replicate your behavior was by removing the call to `skinCheck()` on page load.

My guess is that for some reason this function is not being called on each page load. Adding a simple `console.log` call to the top of the function would let you know if this is the case or not. For example:

```js
function skinCheck() {
    var skin = localStorage.getItem("skin") || 'default';

    $(".subStyle").attr('href', "style/" + skin + '.css');
    $('select option[value="' + skin + '"]').attr("selected", true);

    console.log('Setting page style (post jquery load)');
}

skinCheck();
```

Replication: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-ioana-b0n16z?file=/index.html

One note here, the page is expected to be a bit jittery on load as jQuery and your themes CSS may take a bit to load. One way around this in this architecture is to have a loading state that turns opaque and then goes away covering the page until the theme is loaded.

Comment: It is being called, I did the console log thing

Comment: Interesting, I just saw the update, when attempting to replicate it does not get called. I'll update the answer soon

Comment: @DennisM When I updated it as you updated the question it seems to work just fine. Could you elaborate on what your console.log is showing?

Comment: It just shows whatever skin is being displayed on the page at the time.

Comment: Does it follow up with any errors?

Comment: No.  Oddly enough, this time when I tested it, it seemed to work.  Weird

Comment: WAIT!  It seems this only happens on firefox!

Comment: Ohh well that makes more sense, let me look into that

Comment: My replication works just fine in Firefox for me